# Columns on ssrs column chart are misaligned with labels

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am in a bit of a predicament.  I am trying to fix some formatting issues on a column chart on an ssrs report and my columns and labels are misaligned depending on what parameters i choose.  I am pulling in a count of activity by county on this particular report.

If i choose County A, I get the following output:[misaligned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2d4p.png)
[image]

Data for County A:[misaligned dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZSz6.png)

If I choose County B, I get the following output:[perfect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQLyi.png)
[image]

Data for County B:[perfect dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzdP9.png)

Any ideas?  I just can't figure out why it's ok for some parameter combinations and not for others.

Comment: Can you show both the dataset results, one when run with A and again when run with B.

Comment: added in pictures of the datasets.  let me know if that will work or not.